# segmentation fault when calling close on ifstream object

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I am trying to read a text file into a two dimensional character array. When I call close on the ifstream object after extracting the data, I get a segmentation fault.

This works:

```
problem::problem(obj *o1, obj* o2, char *state_file)
{
ifstream infile;
string line;
infile.open(state_file, ios::in);
getline(infile,line);
infile.close();
}
```

This doesnt:

```
problem::problem(obj *o1, obj* o2, char *state_file)
{

ifstream infile;
string line;

//data is char data[6][7] and is declared in the header
//line is EXACTLY 7 characters lone

infile.open(state_file, ios::in);
for(int i = 5;i >= 0;i--)
{
    getline(infile,line);
    for(int j = 0;j < 7;j++)
        data[i][j] = line[j];
}
cerr << "PROGRAM OK" << endl;
infile.close();
cerr << "The program doesn't get here" << endl;
//Some more constructor code    

}
```

Why am I getting a segmentation fault when I call infile.close()?

SSCCE version that works with the same input file:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class func
{
    public:
        func(char *);   
    private:
        char data[6][7];

};

func::func(char *state_file)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string line;

    infile.open(state_file, ios::in);   
        for(int i = 5;i >= 0;i--)
    {
        getline(infile,line);
        for(int j = 0;j < 7;j++)
            data[i][j] = line[j];
    }

    infile.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func *obj = new func(argv[1]);  
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

From main:

```
obj *p1 = new obj(&something);
obj *p2 = new obj(&something);

problem *p;

if(argc == 3)
    p = new problem(p1, p2, argv[2]); //SEGFAULTS HERE
else
    p = new problem(p1, p2);
```

from the header with the class declaration:

```
public:
    problem(obj *, obj *);
    problem(obj *, obj *, char *);
private:
        char data[6][7];
```

Comment: What if `line` contains less than 7 characters?

Comment: Sorry for the error. The line will always have 7 characters.

Comment: Can you provide a full example that will reproduce this: http://sscce.org/ What you have posted looks reasonable, but this kind of array kerjiggery is tricky, and there may be something in the code we can't see.

Comment: Like this: `#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    
std::ifstream infile;
std::string line;
std::string state_file="foo.txt";

char data[6][7] = {{0}};

infile.open(state_file.c_str(), std::ios::in);
for(int i = 5;i >= 0;i--)
{
    getline(infile,line);
    if (line.size() != 7)
        std::cerr << "Line length is " << line.size() << std::endl;
    for(int j = 0;j < 7 && j<line.size();j++)
        data[i][j] = line[j];
}
std::cerr << "PROGRAM OK" << std::endl;
infile.close();
std::cerr << "The program doesn't get here" << std::endl;
}`& contents of foo.txt.

Comment: Does the code from my comment compile, run, and fail to segfault on your system?  (with `"foo.txt"` replaced with a path to the actual file)

Comment: Nicer formatting than a comment: http://ideone.com/7Nc60h

Comment: Interesting. The edited version I am about to post works with the same input file.

Comment: Yakk, that works fine with the input file I am using. All of the lines are 7 characters.

Comment: So you want us to find what is wrong based on your example that works correctly? You will need to build your example up towards the real code until it fails, or strip the real code back until it is postable but still fails. Or just post the entire thing I suppose, but people will be reluctant to trawl through a lot of code.

Comment: I figured it out, it won't let me self answer because I don't have enough reputation.  The problem had something to do with how the object file was being linked during the build process. Removing all the .o files and rebuilding from scratch solved the problem. Thank you everyone for your input. I apologize for not doing a clean build from the beginning and wasting your time.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but in future, please at least post a *full* example. I just wasted a few minutes putting together the bits you posted into something that I *thought* would closely resemble your actual code (.cpp and .h files, class definition, etc). If I had been able to exactly copy/paste your code, I might have seen no problem, and been able to say "It works, maybe something wrong with your build process".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem had something to do with how the object file was being linked during the build process. Removing all the .o files and rebuilding from scratch solved the problem. Thank you everyone for your input. I apologize for not doing a clean build from the beginning and wasting your time.

Comment: This just helped me again. Not sure how this error happens, but thank you for posting this.

Comment: Was sure to have made a clean build, but obviously not. The error arised during ifstream open() in my case: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your file always contains at least six lines?

The usual way to "iterate" on a ifstream is:

```
ifstream is("test.txt");
string line;
while(getline(is, line))
{
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The input file is more than six lines, the rest are formatted differently and read later.